# Need dynamic keys for a JSON Object Literal

Tags: javascript, json

I need to declare a JSON object literal. One of the keys needs to be calculated at runtime, like so :

```
        var someCalculatedKeyValue = "blah" + "blah";
        var obj = {
            x: "foo",
            someCalculatedKeyValue: "bar"
        }
```

It doesn't seem possible to use generated keys in object literals am I right? The only way around this I can see is to program it like this :

```
        var someCalculatedKeyValue = "blah" + "blah";
        var obj = {
            x: "foo",
        }

        obj[someCalculatedKeyValue] = "bar"
```

Comment: You answered your own question. It is perfectly valid to access members of an object by their key name in the following way: `obj[keyName]`, where `keyName` is generated dynamically.

Comment: You can do it with object literals on ES6 through [computed properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

Comment: Another way to accomplish a string as a key is to put it in the object definition: `var obj = { 'this is a key': 'some value' }` edit: apparently you can't build the key as a string in the object definition

Comment: @MinusFour The correct terminology is "computed property names".

Comment: What is the question?